# How do I create a UTCTime from Int values, using the thyme library in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, time, haskell-thyme

I've got a year, month, day, hour and minute value (all of them are of type `Int`) - how can I convert these to a `UTCTime` or `UniversalTime`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following imports are required:

```
import Control.Lens
import Data.Thyme.Clock
import Data.Thyme.Calendar
```

And then:

```
makeUtcTime :: Year -> Month -> DayOfMonth -> Int -> UTCTime
makeUtcTime y m d x =  UTCTime ((YearMonthDay y m d)^.from gregorian) (toEnum x) ^. from utcTime
```

Within ghci:

```
:t makeUtcTime 2020 1 1 9143892431
makeUtcTime 2020 1 1 9143892431 :: UTCTime
```

(Perhaps there's a simpler way, but this is not too bad)

Comment: This actually seems to give a type of `UTCView` `:t UTCTime ((YearMonthDay 2018 7 21)^.from gregorian) (toEnum 0)UTCTime ((YearMonthDay 2018 7 21)^.from gregorian) (toEnum 0)
  :: UTCView`.