# How do I create a UTCTime value using the time library in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, haskell-time

I've got a year, month, day, hour and minute value (all of them are of type Int) - how can I convert these to a `UTCTime`?

Just as [How do I create a UTCTime from Int values, using the thyme library in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51465700/how-do-i-create-a-utctime-from-int-values-using-the-thyme-library-in-haskell) but using the `time` library instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
import Data.Time.Calendar
import Data.Time

example :: UTCTime
example = UTCTime (fromGregorian 2018 10 27) (secondsToDiffTime 0)
```

Comment: You should probably use [secondsToDiffTime](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.9.2/docs/Data-Time-Clock.html#v:secondsToDiffTime) or [picosecondsToDiffTime](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.9.2/docs/Data-Time-Clock.html#v:picosecondsToDiffTime) instead `toEnum`.

Answer (score 3):

Putting it here for reference. Check two methods parseTimeM and parseTimeOnError. Both you can get from [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.8.0.3/docs/Data-Time-Format.html).
parseTimeM is safe version while parseTimeOnError is unsafe (throws exception).

I had used parseTimeOnError before. You will need to convert the given information in string in specific format and call the function with format and the string as input.

```
import Data.Time
import Data.Time.Format
import Data.Time.Clock
import Text.Printf

getDateString :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> String
getDateString year month day hour minute = (printf "%02d" month) ++ "/" ++ (printf "%02d" day) ++ "/" ++ show year ++ " " ++ show hour ++ ":" ++ show minute

getTheUTCDate :: String -> UTCTime 
getTheUTCDate strDate = parseTimeOrError True defaultTimeLocale "%D %R" strDate

main = do 
          let p = getDateString 12 7 6 23 45 
          print ("Hello ", " ", getTheUTCDate p)
```